# Why are there equal send transactions for each receive on Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, transaction-fees, sending, receiving

I've lunched a new Bitcoin core wallet, and generated some addresses using it. Then I tried to **receive** some BTC to these address, and then, found out if I receive some BTC, there are equal **send** transactions too on the same address.
All incoming BTCs are in my wallet, and there is not any problem up to now. But I wonder to know what are that **send** transactions? I am paying fees for them automatically!

This is an example:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3PiCVEFLHPiexXf15UB7nw9yBMZTWjP73C

Comment: Is your balance not what you expect it to be? Are you making transactions after you have received Bitcoin? Have you shared your wallet.dat file with someone else or received your wallet.dat file from someone else? Seeing sends like this either means that your private keys have been compromised, or you are misunderstanding how Bitcoin works. Bitcoin Core does not randomly produce transactions.

Comment: @AndrewChow the balance is what I am expected, and I had transactions  after receiving BTCs. The strange thing is the same address which I had receives on, has the same amount that is send to somewhere else. Maybe I misunderstand the mechanism of Bitcoin core as a newbie in this platform.

Comment: You can only "send from" an address the amount that it has already received. So it is not unexpected that you see the same amount being sent elsewhere. If you are sending transactions, then you should not be surprised that Core is "sending from" addresses in your wallet.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewChow. Although, I did not say what address should be used to send BTC to other addresses and Bitcoin core seems managed this itself.